# how to fix error cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository base on centos6

Tags: centos, centos6

i'm trying to install the .rpm file but there's an error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security                                                             
Setting up Group Process                                                                                                
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile                                                                              
http://vault.centos.org/6.10/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] problem making ssl 
connection                   
Trying other mirror.                                                                                                    
http://vault.centos.org/6.10/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] problem making ssl 
connection                   
Trying other mirror.                                                                                                    
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: C6.10-base. Please 
verify its path and try again
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know what to provide